# Since so many books are translated into so many languages

Tags: translation

...how can one be sure the translation is correct unless one speaks that language? Prime example: The Bible. 
This book (for the purpose of keeping religious arguments nonexistent here, its a piece of literature), and other writings convey the same general idea...but is the authors specific message being brought across once it is translated?